# Update on Windows 10 cannot connect when behind domain proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, windows-server-2012, windows-domain, windows-10

My computer sits on a network and I think it has Microsoft Server 2012 on there. Without joining the domain; when I first browsed the internet it asked for my domain credentials. I added them in and told it to remember them.

So I can access the internet via the webbrowser... also the install (web-based) for Visual studio 2015 is happily downloading. But windows Update just freezes and does nothing. Windows defender cannot update its definitions either.

I'm guessing its an issue with the domain proxy.

I tried telling windows update (via the registry) to not use the WUS server. Didn't help. I can join the domain with windows 10, but when I try to login it gets stuck setting up the user account.

Any guesses how to get windows update to behave?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled windows 7. Got up and running then did the Windows 10 upgrade again. But this time I choose to keep all my previous settings. Seems to have done the trick.