# Windows 10 update cannot connect (behind a firewall and a proxy)

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, proxy, firewall

I need to set up some windows 10 computers.
I notice that from inside the company's domain, under a firewall and a proxy, Windows updates do NOT work.
I verified that they work correctly if performed from outside the proxy and firewall, so definitely I think that the problem is something dealing with them.

What are the configurations for the firewall and the proxy, in order to make Windows updates run correctly?

I already checked other questions and answers, such as:

[Update on Windows 10 cannot connect when behind domain proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/948214/update-on-windows-10-cannot-connect-when-behind-domain-proxy)

[Windows 10 update cannot connect (behind a firewall)](https://superuser.com/questions/1015558/windows-10-update-cannot-connect-behind-a-firewall)

but they seem not to address my same problem. Also the proposed solutions do not apply.

Also note that the Windows updates used to work for Windows 7.

Any suggestion?

thanks!